# Custom actionbar remove left margin for logo

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom actionbar layout with no paddings and margins for image. But when I run the app I see some space between left screen border and logo.

On image logo is black rectangle. How to remove this space and make logo stick to the left screen side?

[image]

Comment: its better if you remove custom action bar and use a relative layout of fix height say 50 or 60dp and then customize it liek action bar

Comment: You can Ref the stackoverflow [Android: remove left margin from actionbar's custom layout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the logo/home button of the ActionBar just disable it.

add this in your `onCreate()`

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @ElizavetaIvanova how did you theme your action bar?