# Removing left margin from android navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Can anybody help me to find the way to remove the left margin of the navigation drawer icon (mentioned by red rectangle below )?
I am using toolbar here.

[image]

Comment: is the drawer icon 16dp form the left?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout

Comment: I don't know. How can I find that out?

Comment: This is not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

This removes the left margin from toolbar.

```
mainToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

Or you can set left inset to 0dp in toolbar xml:

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
```

Other way is to define that padding in the styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
  <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

If all of these solutions didn't worked please check if the image has its own padding..