# how to remove left margin of Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-design-library

I'm trying to use toolbar for my project.
Here is the code I am using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_padding_8dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_padding_16dp"
            android:text="AppBar"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: toolbar]


I want to remove left margin, Here I set **android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"** and **android:contentInsetStart="0dp"** but it's **not** working..Please help me !

Comment: change to use app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" and
app:contentInsetStart="0dp". add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to most parent view xml

Comment: @calvinfly thanks for the answer .. works like a charm ..

Comment: This is not left margin, Its Toolbar inner side space so we call toolbar left padding and you can remove left padding.
[Remove Space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58690606/5788247)

Comment: [possible duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27354812/3763032) @natuan241

Comment: this link was useful for me, try it...
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout)

Answer (score 51):

replace your xml with below xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_padding_8dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp" 
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_padding_16dp"
        android:text="AppBar"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With navigationIcon, add `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`

Answer (score 49):

Use `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` to remove that left space.

Answer (score 13):

See the below code and here I added `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`. You need to add that to your code because before API 21 (i.e. Lollipop) you need to add that line.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            >
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

Referring to @calvinfly comment:

I updated my code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/titleString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#468bac"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlStarsTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/txtRatings"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:max="5"
            android:rating="3.7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add these two lines in your toolbar.xml

1. app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
2. app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

Answer (score 2):

This works for me...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app2:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>
```

Comment: you have to emphasize the xmlns part on the toolbar, it seems when you auto add it, it adds to the top most parent, and that doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Add below xml code to your Toolbar !

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following code to your `.xml` file It may solve. Perfectly working solution I have tried.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/toolbarPopup">
```

> above 21 use following code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This **Toolbar property** for remove toolbar left space

> app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below xml code to your Toolbar**

```
<android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
   android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
   app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
   app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
   android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
   android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
   app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
   app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
```