# How to overcome gap between navigation icon and activity label?

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

I want to reduce this space is there any way to do this?[image: Thanks in advanced.]

This is my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: Post your *style.xml* file.

Comment: Thanks for your response you can check now.

Comment: Please refer below mentioned answer link, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38562969/3940292

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove large padding after hamburger (menu) icon in Android Toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373481/remove-large-padding-after-hamburger-menu-icon-in-android-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to your Toolbar:

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"  
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"  
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```