# Align layout to extreme left inside Toolbar android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to align imageview to the extreme left of my toolbar but it's not happening. I tried other solutions on stackoverflow but none is working for me

[image: check out this image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/app_icon_book_sumary_one" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: is this image your result ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove left margin of Android Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063962/how-to-remove-left-margin-of-android-toolbar)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding these 2 lines inside toolbar worked

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: for me only the line already app:contentInsetStart="0dp" solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Set this attribute on your toolbar

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp
```

Comment: it doesn't work... toolbar is already on extreme left but in the LinearLayout there is some margin, i dont know why

Comment: I can see on your picture that the toolbar is not aligned to the left completely

Comment: my cursor is on LinearLayout so it is showing the border of linear layout. When the cursor is on toolbar the border moves to the extreme left. :)

Comment: then try paddingStart="0dp"  on the toolbar