# android Bottom app bar is not taking full width even after setting width to match parent

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, bottomnavigationview

My bottom app bar is holding bottom navigation view and its shoqing little black strip on left side(pls check [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjNp.png)
) even after setting width to match_parent.

It works fine when I use bottom navigation view without bottom app bar but I want both of them together,

I have tried setting margins right but still it does not move to left and take full width.

My layout file is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.recipeapp.marathi.activities.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_adunit_id">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>





        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bottomappbar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomappbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:background="@drawable/round_nav"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_navigation" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Relevant documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar#attr_android:contentInsetStart)

This question has also been awnsered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562969/8139260) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320632/8139260)

```xml
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

in your `com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar` is but far the simplest

Sample code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bottomappbar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_navigation"
                />
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomappbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
```

Comment: Fab button is going behind navigation view so I wrapped it with bottom bar, pls tell solution

Comment: I was wrong, I've edited my solution it should be what you want

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked, but what does these attributes mean? @Teh

Comment: It just removes the inset which the toolbar has by default I have edited the answer to include more information

Comment: I searched on docs about insets and did not find ContentsetStart or ContentInsetEnd attribute, why bottom app bar does not take full width by default?