# Android - Setting default style for EditText view is not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to set default style for edit text view. In this example, I have set default style for editText as well as for textView.

Here is my styles.xml from values folder:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

As shown in the snapshots below, I have added two editText and two textView in layout.

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        style="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="EditText1" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="EditText2" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the issue is, default style for textView works fine but for editText view it does not reflect the style. If I explicitly set style for editText  then it reflects as expected (as done for editText1), but not by default. Text color for editText2 should be red but it's not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

#### Hi prashant..just i copied your code in my project. for me its working

#### do you want like this? or anything else?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but without explicitly specifying style for every editText view. It's still showing same behavior at my end. I am using eclipse and another thing that I just observed is, when I switch to API level 21 the layout preview shows it as expected. Only at API level 14 and below layout preview does not reflect style by default. But on actual device it does not reflecting style, not even on API 19. I tried on 10 and 19.

Comment: Any luck? Could you reproduce the issue at your end?

Comment: use API 19 only..why are you changing again to 14

Comment: Because I want my app to support devices from API level 10 onwards. And it's showing the same behavior on all devices regardless of API level.

Comment: for me its working if i keep min SDK as 10, max SDK is 21, this thing tell me do you want  same as i have shown you in image or not???if yes give me your email id , i will email you the source file

Comment: check your inbox and run it. if you want anything different just let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83168/discussion-between-prashant-and-madhu-sudhan).