# extra margin on left side of actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I am new to android, working on my first App .I am stuck at a problem, I see extra margin in the action bar when I run my App on API 18 and above .

I googled and found this answer :-
 [Android: remove left margin from actionbar's custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout/27979007#27979007)

But I don't think this its applicable to me,
Firstly,(As per the solution suggested in the link above)
1)I am not using a toolbar, but a actionbar 
2)Android Studio throws error for the below code

```
        Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Saying, minimum is 14 and setContentInsetsAbsolute needs API 21.
So I did this ,

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 21 ){
        Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
 }
```

But this is not helping.
Where am I going wrong and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you using Toolbar as Action Bar via setSupportActionBar function?

Comment: I am using an actionbar (Customised ).
A simple Layout using relative tag , 
and using
'ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 21 ){
             Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
            parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
        }
'
In the activity to set.