# Custom ActionBar does not fill in android Tablets?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tablet

I have an Custom ActionBar in which i did not use Toolbar. At First i encountered that the width did not fill the whole screen (There were gap from both left and right side). but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout) answer it solved my problem.

this is my code,

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, layoutParams);
        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

Now this solution did work for phones though but for Tablets the same problem remains.
please any help would be appreciated!!!!