# Android constraint layout strange behavior

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

The version of my  constraint layout is `1.0.0-alpha8` . After I have included a toolbar in my layout , there is space in both left and right side of the toolbar, like the image below

[image]

Here is the code for my toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Which I have included in my layout in following way

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_top"
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

I didn't used any additional padding or margin in my root element of the layout file .

Another stange thing is if I compile or build the program my code automatically changed, like

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_top"
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Change to

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_top"
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="368dp"/>
```

And the guideline also add some additional value which I didn't write, like `layout_editor_absoluteX` automatically added .

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"/>
```

Comment: Target SDK & Which theme is using?

Comment: @AnkitaShah         targetSdkVersion 24 and theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: Try this
 `Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
    parent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);//for tab otherwise give space in tab
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);`
Or Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28086802/6005977

Comment: @AnkitaShah my question is why is it showing this in preview and add extra code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you should update to ConstraintLayout beta 4.

Now, the root problem you have is that you are using `match_parent` on the toolbar -- this isn't supported by ConstraintLayout. You need to add:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

and use `0dp` instead of match_parent:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_top"
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Note that you can create those attributes easily by doing right-click on the component, and picking [image]

On Android Studio 2.2 you need to hold the  key to create the constraints, on Android Studio 2.3 it creates the constraints by default.