# android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" vs app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to remove left space of `toolbar`. I see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320632/2455259 which seems working for me. I am unable to understand what is the meaning to add `android` and `app` namespace for same attribute.

Is there any difference between them ? `android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" vs app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android` namespace is reserved for views that are in the Android Framework.

On the other hand, `app` namespace is for views from support library.

So, in this case `android` will be applied to `Toolbar` that is shipped within Android SDK - `android.widget.ToolBar`. And `app` 
will be applied to the `Toolbar` that comes with support libraries.

Obviously, there's no need to apply both `android` and `app` to the same view, because it is either from Android SDK or from support library.

Answer (score 1):

`android:contentInsetLeft` should be used with the native `Toolbar` `android.widget.ToolBar` while `app:contentInsetLeft` has to be used with the `Toolbar` from the support library `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. As rule of thumb, `res-auto` namespace is used with the support-library