# Too much margin on SearchView

Tags: android

My SearchView is showing up like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a margin both on the `search_edit_frame` of the SearchView, and outside the SearchView itself.

[image]

Where is this coming from? Inspecting the layout reveals a margin of 24 pixels to the left of  `search_edit_frame` but no margin elsewhere.

How can I remove this extra space?

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/appbar_menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    (...)
</RelativeLayout>
```

I managed to reduce the spacing by applying @Jimmy's answer:

[image]

However theres still a big gap between the "back" imagebutton and the SearchView.

Comment: Please put your xml code as well.

Comment: @Yashajabiya i posted it now

Comment: The behavior you see is a consequence of how `Toolbar` layouts its children. Basically, all of the `MenuItem`s would be laid out from right to left (in the case of rtl - from left to right). Inspect [`Toolbar#layoutChildRight()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java#1953): `childWidth` is the value, that affects on how much margin would be between back arrow and `SearchView`. I would recommend to stick to `Toolbar` with custom layout, as long as there is no API to resolve the issue.

Comment: May be your search icon and back icon image have more extra white space.
Open you images in any image editing tool like photoshop and try to reduce the white space(transparent area).

Comment: Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: No i havent... I guess Ill have to use a custom toolbar layout

Answer (score 2):

`search_edit_frame` is a `LinearLayout` in `searchview` layout. It has start and end margin of 8dip by default .

relevant code from [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml)

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layoutDirection="locale">
```

Your issue is probably because of start margin on it. You can get this linear layout from search view and set the layout parameter to reduce the gap in your activity ( probably inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` or similar where you are inflating this`searchview` ) .

Something like this ,  assuming `searchView` is your SearchView instance,

```
        LinearLayout searchFrameLL=(LinearLayout)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMargins(0,0,8,0); //params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
       // params.setMarginStart(0);  //(or just use individual like this
        searchFrameLL.setLayoutParams(params);
```

In similar fashion, you can update other properties in that xml to meet your needs.

Comment: thanks, im going to try but the margin I show is way more than only 8dp, dont you think?

Comment: this does reduce the spacing a bit but its still too much wasted space, theres a gap that i cannot identify!

Comment: that brought your left margin on search frame to 0. now you can try to reduce right margin for the `back` button as well.

Comment: @MichelReap have you tried to use `contentInsetEnd/Right="0dp"` for your `Toolbar`? It should help to remove the remained margin of your back button.

Comment: yes i have, also if i use landscape searchview stays at the far right!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but I also had an unwanted margin in the Toolbar view. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout)  about content insets helped me figure it out.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/primaryColor"
     android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
     android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
     app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
     app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
     android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
     android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
     app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
     app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

Comment: This did not change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

There will be small padding as it a `MenuItem`. You can reset the content Inset padding. try setting attribute `contentInsetStartWithNavigation` to 0dp.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `leftMargin` to zero to achieve desired result:

```
LinearLayout searchEditFrame = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchEditFrame.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="right"` on the view.

Comment: does not do anything!

Answer (score 0):

For **kotlin**:

```
var searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
val searchEditFrame: LinearLayout =
searchView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.search_edit_frame) as LinearLayout
val layoutParams: LinearLayout.LayoutParams =
searchEditFrame.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
layoutParams.leftMargin = -10
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late, but I'll post here my solution in case it helps anyone. My `SearchView` is under app bar and always visible, but the excessive `margin` between the start of the view and the icon it's still present. My solution it's on the `xml` where the `SearchView` is declared, i just added:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingStart="-5dp"
```