# .NET MAUI modify Android Toolbar

Tags: android, .net, maui, toolbar

This is my first MAUI app attempt and I haven't built any apps with Xamarin.
At the time of posting this my project is still using .NET 7 and I am focusing on developing Windows and Android platforms. I have been able to modify the default Android toolbar with a couple of methods

`NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);`
`NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, NavGrid);`

The NavGrid takes the place of the default toolbar but have found that there is a default padding set on Android Toolbar wrapper.

I have found a solution from [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout#:%7E:text=However%2C%20it%20is%20possible%20to,following%20property%20to%20Toolbar%20widget.&text=Just%20add%20app%3AcontentInsetStart%3D%22,XML%20attribute%20of%20the%20toolbar.&text=This%20should%20be%20good%20enough.&text=Only%20add%20app%3AcontentInsetStart%3D%22,toolbar%20remove%20that%20left%20space.) (which includes images showing the problem I am having), but am not sure how to translate it to MAUI code. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new .xml file and add the style in it.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Maui.SplashTheme">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then, you can use the .xml file in the MainActivity.cs file (Platforms/Android):

```
[Activity(
    //Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme",
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
    MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When running in debug mode, the app crashed on the Splash Screen. I created new xml (tired a couple of names, Styles.xml, SplashTheme.xml), file and added it to the Platforms>Android>Resources>values directory. I got 23 entries in the stack trace.  About halfway up the stack trace there is an entry that made some sense to me: Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:661).

Comment: I started looking into `ToolbarHandler.Mapper` for a solution to my original issue (padding in the Android toolbar wrapper element).

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, `ToolbarHandler` was the way to solve the issue I was having. `var materialToolbar = handler.PlatformView;` then I was able to call `materialToolbar.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);`.